# Merging Errors: Error: Attribute application@appComponentFactory in android 28.0.3

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-9.0-pie

Merging Errors: Error: Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:39:5-738:19 to override.

in android 28.0.3  i want solution without migrating androidx. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As it's suggested why you don't add

```
android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
```

to mainfest application tag.and if you want to use suport library rather than androidx please don't try to use libraries that use androidx.

Comment: now it gives errors
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':CrushOnTube@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:12.0.1.

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':CrushOnTube@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:cardview-v7:[26.0.0, 27.99.99].


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':CrushOnTube@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0, 27.99.99].

i dont want to use androidx

Comment: now getting 
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':CrushOnTube@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:12.0.1.

Comment: why you don't want to use androidx.i think google will stopp developing support library if it didn't already did.you'll have alot of problem because of mixing things.

Comment: after migrating to androidx

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':CrushOnTube@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
Show Details

same error

Comment: i stuck in these error whatever i do these errors will come

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':CrushOnTube@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:12.0.1

Comment: if you have teamview i can help you for free